# In a Linux script, how to remove all files & directories but one, in current directory?

Tags: linux, shell

In a shell script, I want to remove all files and directories but one file, in the current directory. 
I used

```
 ls | grep -v 'nameoffiletokeep' | xargs rm
```

this removes files, but directories are not deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -iname nameoffiletokeep -print0| xargs -0 rm -rf;
```

This finds all files and directories that are direct children of the current working directory that are *not* named `nameoffiletokeep` and removes them all (recursively for directories), regardless of leading dots (e.g. `.hidden`, which would be missed if you used a glob like `rm -rf *`), spaces, or other metachars in the file names.

I've used `-iname` for case-insensitive matching against `nameoffiletokeep`, but if you want case-sensitivity, you should use `-name`. The choice should depend on the underlying file system behavior, and your awareness of the letter-case of the file name you're trying to protect.

Comment: GNU find has a -delete flag for this use case.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon, good point, I didn't know about that option. However, I'm usually reluctant to use `find` ACTION options that are not purely printing. The rationale is that non-printing commands can fail unexpectedly, which will terminate the entire find command. I've encountered this with things like `-exec grep`, which can fail to find a match in the subset of found items that are passed to a particular invocation of grep in the invocation sequence (could be multiple invocations for a large number of matches). I guess `-delete` is less risky, but still, I'd prefer `xargs -0 rm -rf`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bash, you can use extended globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -fr !(nameoffiletokeep)
```

In zsh the same idea is possible:

```
setopt extended_glob
rm -fr ^nameoffiletokeep
```